# Are my solutions correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, logic, metric-spaces

> $\operatorname{Q.1-}$Is it correct to say that in a metric space the empty set is a neighbourhood of each of its points?Justify your answer.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.Since,$\emptyset \subset X$.

Let $x\in \emptyset \implies \exists \epsilon>0$ such that $x\in B(x,\epsilon) $.But, $\emptyset $ does not contain any element then the implication holds vacuously.
**Hence,in a metric space the empty set is a neighbourhood of each of its points.**

> $\operatorname{Q.2-}$Can a non-empty finite set be a neighbourhood of any of its points in a metric space?

Let $X=${$p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n$} & let $d$ be the discrete metric on $X$.

Now,let $p_i \in X$ then {$p_i$} is nbhd of $p_i$ as $p_i\in ${$p_i$}.

Comment: Both answers are correct.

Comment: Please supply your definition of "neighborhood of $x$". Should not $x$ be an element of that neighborhood, thus disqualifying the empty set?

Comment: @LutzL:Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.A set $N \subset X$ is said to be  neighbourhood of a point $p \in X$ if there exists an $\epsilon $>0such that $B(p,\epsilon) \subset N$.

Comment: And obviously you always have $p\in B(p,ϵ)$. There is no implication, thus no assumption to negate. Your reasoning in 1.) is wrong.

Comment: @LutzL:What should be the correct reasoning?

Comment: @LutzL:SEE the edit.Is it correct now?

Comment: No, the conclusion should be that the empty set is a neighborhood of no point at all.

Comment: @LutzL:I'm not getting how to do this.

Comment: @AashiqRaza, you are correct, the empty set is a neighbourhood of each point in the empty set. Your reasoning (that it is a vacuous truth, since the empty set contains no points at all) is a correct argument. The only way you could be wrong is if in "a neighbourhood of each of its points", the *it* refers to $X$ instead of to $\emptyset$ -- but it seems like a big stretch to me to interpret the sentence that way.

Comment: @LutzL: You are wrong, and Aashiq is correct.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: The "its" in Q1 most likely refers to "metric space", not empty set. This is a mathematical task, not a linguistic trap. -- And saying "all the points in the empty set" is the same as "no point at all". -- One should stop parsing the answer to Q1 at '$x\in∅$, as no such  $x$ exists.

Comment: Further common sense: the task is about the topology of $(M,d)$, not the (quite trivial) relative topology of the empty set.

Comment: @LutzL, learning about vacuous truths is important, and not just an exercise in trick questions. The empty set naturally fits into many propositions because of it. For instance, "each open set is a neighbourhood of all of its points".